# else clause in pmml derivedfield

Tags: sas, pmml

In derivedfield in pmml, for making local transformation I used the code below

```
<MapValues outputColumn="longForm">
  <FieldColumnPair field="gender" column="shortForm"/>
  <InlineTable>
    <row><shortForm>m</shortForm><longForm>male</longForm>
    </row>
    <row><shortForm>f</shortForm><longForm>female</longForm>
    </row>
  </InlineTable>
</MapValues>
```

In that code if shortform is m it returns "male", and if shortform is f it returns "female". Also I want want to add else clause for that code. If shortfrom is not m or f it should returns "unknown". How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify [`MapValues@defaultValue`](http://dmg.org/pmml/v4-2-1/Transformations.html#xsdElement_MapValues) attribute:

```
<MapValues outputColumn="longForm" defaultValue="unknown">
  ...
</MapValues>
```